# Is there an "all except (...)" union discriminator in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

It may be the easiest to start with an example:

```js
enum Season {
    Spring,
    Summer,
    Autumn,
    Winter
}
    
interface WinterForecast {
    season: Season.Winter;
    snowfall: number;
}
    
interface RestOfYearForecast {
    season: Season.Spring | Season.Summer | Season.Autumn; // can I shorten this?
    rainfall: number;
}
```

Can I somehow specify the `season` in `RestOfYearForecast` as "everything in Season except Winter" instead of listing all possible values?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion

Comment: Ahh, perfect, thanks. Would you mind posting this as an answer instead?

Answer (score 5):

```
interface RestOfYearForecast {
  season: Exclude<Season, Season.Winter>
  rainfall: number;
}
```